# Compatibilidad de Python y Mac OS

Tags: python, python-2.7, macos

Tengo instala la version 2.7 de python en un Macbook Pro mid 2012, y aparece algo así:

```
WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

El problema es que a pesar de que instale lo que pedían, aun se cierra inesperadamente, alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instala la última versión de ActiveTcl
2. Reinstala python.

Respuesta extraída de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version